# How do I purge appointments in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to purge multiple Google Calendar entries at a time? For example, is there a way to clear a day, week, or month at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this in Google Calendar.  You could import/export the google calendar to another web app or desktop application which has this functionality, make the necessary changes and then sync the calendar back to Google Calendar as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something that has this functionality and can sync with Google Calendar (iCal (Mac OSX) or Evolution (Linux), I'm not sure what can do this on Windows)